# How install MVC 4 in visual studion 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I installed visual studio 2013 for my academic purposes. I'm learning asp.net and mvc4 developments but i cannot find template for mvc  and asp.net web application template. I found few methods how install mvc 4 for visual studio 2010 sp1 but i did not find proper way to install in visual studio 2013 mvc 4 . Guys can anyone help me?

Comment: I installed visual studio 2013 ultimate version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project template should already be installed. Go to `File` -> `New` -> `Project...`. Under `Installed` -> `Templates` -> `Visual C#` -> `Web` -> `Visual Studio 2012`... there should be a template for an "ASP.NET MVC 4 Application". You don't need to install MVC 4 as the references should be pulled in via NuGet.